# How to change order of divs with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap-based layout (made with Visual composer in WP) with alternating rows, with a code looking a bit like this:

```
<div class="custom-row">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="span8">
   <img>
  </div>
  <div class="span4">
   <p>some content</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="custom-row">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="span4">
   <p>some content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="span8">
   <p>some content</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that on a small screen, they are stacked one on top of eachother like so:
- img
- text
- text
- img
But I want to get a stack like: one image / one text, without having 2 texts following eachother. I tried the pull and push trick but it's not doing anything.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Re-ordering columns in the same .row (a row of 12 columns only) is built in to Bootstrap 3, it is not part of Bootstrap 2. Bootstrap 4 is coming out in the next few months, you should upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

It's because your columns are in different divs. Remove them and it should work.

**html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="bordered col-md-9 col-md-push-3">col A</div>
  <div class="bordered col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">col B</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.bordered{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4cbzY/371/

Comment: The OP appears to be using Bootstrap 2, which won't work with your html. Also, by itself, col-12 doesn't exist in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: It's because I reused an existing jsfiddle. col-12 was the name of a css class in the previous one. I updated it to match this answer so it should be ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. But you have old version of bootstrap.

```
<div class="custom-row">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="span8">
   <img>
  </div>
  <div class="span4">
   <p>some content</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="custom-row">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="span8">
   <img>
  </div>
  <div class="span4">
   <p>some content</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```